# Ant: deploy folders with files inside

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

I am using Ant deployment in IntelliJ, and got the following issue. In the configuration `deploy.xml` file there is the following snippet

```
<fileset id = "folder_local" dir = "folder_server">
    <include name = "*.*"/>
</fileset>
```

so that when I do deployment, it copies all the files from the root of `folder_local` on my local drive to `folder_server` on the server. My goal is to copy all the content from `folder_local`, that is not only the files in the root, but also folders, subfolders and files there. For example, if I change the 2nd line to

```
    <include name = "*"/>
```

it will copy also the folders, however their content is not copied. Say, if my `folder_local` contains `test0.py` and `foo\test1.py` then in the former case only `test0.py` is copied to the server, in the latter also the subfolder `foo\` is added, but not its content: file `test1.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all files and directories, you can use the pattern

```
<include name="**/*"/>
```

Your reference is the Patterns section of the [Ant manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/).